# js Как проверить что каждое значение объекта true?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Какой самый бысрый способ проверки, что у объекта КАЖДОЕ значение имеет значенее `true` или `false` ? Есть ли готовый метод ? Пример

```js
let validationConditions = {
  notEmptyName: false,
  notEmptyEmail: false,
  correctEmail: false,
  notEmptyMessage: false,
  validCapcha: true,
}

let validationConditions2 = {
  notEmptyName: true,
  notEmptyEmail: true,
  correctEmail: true,
  notEmptyMessage: true,
  validCapcha: true,
}

const arrValidation = Object.values(validationConditions);
const arrValidation2 = Object.values(validationConditions2);

function checkValues(arr) {
  if (arr.every("true")) {
    console.log("Everything values TRUE")
  } else {
    console.log("No TRUE")
  }
}
checkValues(arrValidation);
checkValues(arrValidation2);
```

что-то на подобии этого... только что б работало. А то [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) тут не по функции фильтрует, а по `string`...

Comment: Готового метода нет. Придется самому изобретать. Ну а реалицая на выбор, либо ключи перебирвать циклом, либо превратить в массив и далее каким то перебирающим методом массива проверять

Comment: У вас вообще ошибка...Вы в every передаете просто строку, а должны передать колбэк. arr.every(el => el === true) и всё заработает...

Comment: Вам нужен, в первую очередь, **самый быстрый** метод или просто рабочий метод? судя по тексту вопроса, вам важна скорость

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если значения только булевые и всегда существуют, то можно обойтись простыми условиями используя [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) :

```js
let validationConditions1 = {
  notEmptyName: false,
  notEmptyEmail: false,
  correctEmail: false,
  notEmptyMessage: false,
  validCapcha: false
};
let validationConditions2 = {
  notEmptyName: true,
  notEmptyEmail: true,
  correctEmail: true,
  notEmptyMessage: true,
  validCapcha: true
};
let validationConditions3 = {
  notEmptyName: true,
  notEmptyEmail: true,
  correctEmail: true,
  notEmptyMessage: false,
  validCapcha: true
};

function checkValues(arr) {
  if (arr.includes(true)) {
    if (!arr.includes(false)) { console.log("Все значения TRUE") }
    else { console.log("Смешанные значения") } }
  else { console.log("Все значения FALSE") }
}

checkValues( Object.values(validationConditions1) );
checkValues( Object.values(validationConditions2) );
checkValues( Object.values(validationConditions3) );
```

Answer (score 1):

> способ проверки, что у объекта КАЖДОЕ значение имеет значенее true или false ?

Вот так можно проверять...

```js
let validationConditions = {
  notEmptyName: false,
  notEmptyEmail: false,
  correctEmail: false,
  notEmptyMessage: false,
  validCapcha: true,
}

let validationConditions2 = {
  notEmptyName: true,
  notEmptyEmail: true,
  correctEmail: true,
  notEmptyMessage: true,
  validCapcha: true,
}

const arrValidation = Object.values(validationConditions);
const arrValidation2 = Object.values(validationConditions2);

function checkValues(arr, type = true) {
  if (arr.every(v => v === type)) {
    console.log("Everything values " + type)
  } else {
    console.log("No " + type)
  }
}
checkValues(arrValidation, false);
checkValues(arrValidation2);
```

Еще вот так можно проверить...

```js
let validationConditions = {
  notEmptyName: false,
  notEmptyEmail: false,
  correctEmail: false,
  notEmptyMessage: false,
  validCapcha: true,
}

let validationConditions2 = {
  notEmptyName: true,
  notEmptyEmail: true,
  correctEmail: true,
  notEmptyMessage: true,
  validCapcha: true,
}

const arrValidation = Object.values(validationConditions);
const arrValidation2 = Object.values(validationConditions2);

function checkValues(arr, type = true) {
  const s = new Set(arr)
  if (s.size === 1 && s.has(type)) {
    console.log("Everything values " + type)
  } else {
    console.log("No " + type)
  }
}
checkValues(arrValidation, false);
checkValues(arrValidation2);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а есть ли способ не превращая объект в массив?  Ведь тут по сути два прохода.... сначала из объекта->массив потом сравнивание.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, есть цикл `for...in` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё интересное решение нашел. В копилку

```js
const myObject = {
  prop1: true,
  prop2: true,
  prop3: true,
};

const allValuesTrue = Object.values(myObject).every((value) => value === true);

console.log(allValuesTrue);
```